# Is this Android click handler using threads correctly?

Tags: java, optimization, android, thread-safety, event-handling

I am implementing a thread like the following.  Is my implementation correct?

It works well, but I need a check.

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Looper.prepare();
                Context context = view.getContext();

                final String      titleItem = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleItem)).getText();
                final String        descItem = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descItem)).getText();
                final Bitmap        bitmap = (Bitmap) ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgItem)).getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                Toast.makeText(context, "Item Title: " + titleItem + ", Item Desc: " + descItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ItemDetails.class);

                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray(); 

                        intent.putExtra("title", titleItem);
                        intent.putExtra("BMP",bytes);
                        intent.putExtra("desc", descItem);

                        Log.i("ON ITEM CLICK", "OK");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                Looper.loop();                        
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
        stopThread(Thread.currentThread());
    }
});
```

Can you please tell me if you see something wrong or if there is a better way of doing the same or to optimize it?

Comment: android has background threads available (with options to callback the main thread when done) so there is no need to roll your own setup

Comment: @ratchetfreak So I don't need to implement this Thread ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@ratchetfreak's comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49317/is-this-implementation-of-thread-available#comment86711_49317) is correct, expanding on it here a bit:

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is the class to use (or rather, extend and use your subclass-implementation, as `AsyncTask` itself is an abstract class).

You should use `AsyncTask` for performing operations that otherwise would block the UI-thread and thus would make your application not respond.

However, let's take a look at what your code actually does:

- Creates a runnable
- Gives the runnable a `View`, from which it takes a `Context`, two `TextView`s (and their `String`s), and a `Bitmap` from an `ImageView`.
- Then it creates and shows a toast - **this should be done on the UI-thread and not in a background thread**
- Posts a runnable to your `myHandler`, **therefore making the following code run on your UI-thread**:

  - Create an intent
  - Compress a bitmap into JPEG
  - Puts some data into the intent
  - Starts a new activity
- After the runnable has been created and a new thread started, you call a method that seems to want to stop your current thread!? Why on earth would you want to do that?? Let Android take care of the thread handling! **That thread is not yours to stop!**

#### Why do you create these threads?

The longest running operation that you perform in these threads is the `Compress a bitmap into JPEG`, **which you run on the UI-thread anyway**. The few things that you do in background is so fast that you really don't need to create a new thread for it.

If your `Compress a bitmap into JPEG` operation takes much time, then I would suggest you create an `AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, byte[]>` to handle that. (`Bitmap` is the input, it does not have any progress update and therefore it says `Void`, and it returns a `byte[]` which you will send to the next activity). I don't think you need any `AsyncTask` at all here though.

#### Your new code:

With the above comments taken into consideration, here's the code you need. No extra threads. If this code causes your app to stop respond for a longer while than what is comfortable, *then* you can consider an `AsyncTask`.

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
            int position, long id) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        String titleItem = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleItem)).getText();
        String descItem = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descItem)).getText();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgItem)).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Item Title: " + titleItem + ", Item Desc: " + descItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ItemDetails.class);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray(); 

        intent.putExtra("title", titleItem);
        intent.putExtra("BMP",bytes);
        intent.putExtra("desc", descItem);
        Log.i("ON ITEM CLICK", "OK");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

#### Normal usage of `AsyncTask`

Whenever you have a *longer running computational-intensive operation*, then you can consider an `AsyncTask`. Also whenever you do network operations (download a file from internet, create a long-running socket-connection, etc.), then you **need** an `AsyncTask`. As said already, I don't think your current code needs/benefits from an `AsyncTask`.

#### Consider, however...

Your `ImageView` known as `view.findViewById(R.id.imgItem)` must have gotten its `drawable` from somewhere. Is it loaded from a file on the external storage? Is it loaded from a resource? Rather than compressing the drawable's bitmap data and sending the byte array, consider informing your new activity about *where it can find the original data*. If it's a file on the external storage, pass along a `String` for the path it is found in. If it's a resource in your application, pass along the resource `int` identifier.

If the `drawable` is loaded from the internet or dynamically created, *then* I agree about compressing it as JPEG and sending the byte array to the new activity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and you explanations. I'll delete my extra Thread then and it'll works.